# How can I check if my UIViewController got viewed when it appears to the user in my Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewwillappear

I have a UIViewController with a button. This button has a segue connected to another UIViewController and the segue is of type `Show`. It looks somehow like this:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("myIdentifier", sender: user)
```

and the function `prepareForSegue` is:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "myIdentifier"){

        if let frD = segue.destinationViewController as? MyNextClass,
        ...
```

Now when user presses the button, the new UIViewController pops out on fullscreen. It also has a button called `exitButton` that does one thing:

```
@IBAction func exitbuttonaction(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

When user presses it - they dismiss this view controller and they see the previous one. That previous container has a `viewWillAppear` function, but it doesn't get called each time user comes back to it from the 2nd controller. Why not, since it appears every time to the user?

Also, is there any other way of distinguishing when the parent controller appeared to the user? (maybe some other function similar to `viewWillAppear` that would work while dismissing the 2nd controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use an `UnwindSegue`. An `UnwindSegue` gives you a way to “unwind” the navigation stack and specify a destination to go back to. Your `viewWillAppear` never call again because already appeared.

If you want to know what a `UnwindSegue` is, you can check this answer: [stackoverflow anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/3701102)

If you want to know how to do it, I recommend these links:

[apple documentation about unwind segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html)

[tutorial about unwind segues](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/04/work-with-unwind-segue-in-swift-language-ios-8/)

[youtube videotutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czh9Nrg0UvY)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.